# cannot remove Cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I'm using the following command to remove an unused Cordova plugin:

```
$ cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-facebook
  Uninstalling cordova-plugin-facebook from android
  Uninstalling cordova-plugin-facebook from its
```

Its giving me the following error:

```
  Error: Uh oh!
  Path must be a string. Received undefined
```

How do I resolve the problem or remove the plugin by hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing that on the line:

```
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-facebook from its
```

That last word should be `ios`? If so, the `ios` platform might need to be removed and re-added:

1. Call `cordova platform rm ios`.
2. Check your `config.xml` file for a `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook"> ...` line. Remove it if it's still there.
3. Call `cordova platform add ios`.

Hopefully that cleans things out properly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to most of @eb1 answer expect for using `cordova` for install/remove it will not work for my case instead use

```
ionic plugin rm
```

Comment: Most definitely! In this particular case, the user had installed the base Apache Cordova product -- so they needed the `cordova` command line. But there are a bunch of frameworks and CLIs that are built on top of Cordova, Ionic being one of them. If you're using one of these frameworks, you'll need to use their tools to add/remove the plugins.