# Path must be a string. Received undefined while uninstall plugin from ionic 2

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic2

i am using bellow command to remove plugin from ionic 2 app.

`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-admobpro`

its display following error.

```
Chaitanyas-iMac:NearByApp chaitanya$ cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-admobpro
Uninstalling 1 dependent plugins.
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-extension from android
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-admobpro from android
Uninstalling 1 dependent plugins.
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-extension from ios
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-admobpro from ios
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Error: Uh oh!
Path must be a string. Received undefined
```

how can i resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot remove Cordova plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322627/cannot-remove-cordova-plugin)

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: after installing this plugin i build the app using `ionic build ios` then its build succesfully but then i run on xcode then it is showing `build fail.` in have remove plugin and tried to build on xcode then its working. @Sampath

Comment: Now no issues for you?

Comment: i want to use `Admob` banner in my project. so i will install it again and check it.